# In which mode are you after typing 'r' from NORMAL mode?

Tags: vim

In which mode are you after typing 'r' from NORMAL mode?

I know that it is for replacing just one character and that it is different from REPLACE mode.

But which mode is it? INSERT? NORMAL?

Additionaly, how can I do a mapping for when I am in this situation?

I have searched the documentation and Google of course, ran numerous tests, but couldn't figure this out.

Answer (score 3):

See `:help r`. It's the normal mode "replace" command. It changes a single character under the cursor. If your cursor is on the "f" in "foo", and you type "rg", you'll have "goo".

You don't leave normal mode when doing this. Insert mode bindings are not honored, either. No special bindings are honored for modifying this behavior directly.

*Edited to clarify that you're in normal mode the whole time.*